# NumberFormatException while parsing numeric value from property file?

Tags: java, properties-file, numberformatexception

I am trying to get values in my Java program from a property file, which is written using a python script on a server machine.

The program works fine locally, but on the server I get **Null pointer Exception** when I try to convert integer values in property file into variables of my program, **for example** :

```
db_port=34
```

I do:

```
int a =  Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("db_port").trim());
```

As I mentioned earlier this only causes problems on the server, but on localhost it works fine.
This happens to my client and middleware machine as well.
Both have the same error that stops at this retreiving property values from the file.
But on the localhost I write a property file manually,on the server it is generated using this script.

The way I write the property file is in a configuration file that has the values and my script takes values from there and writes them to a property file to be put on different machines (IN PYTHON):

```
prop_file_on_local_machine_S = '%s/middleware.properties'%directory
with open(prop_file_on_local_machine_S,'w') as f:

        for keys in configFile.options("middleware_props"):
          f.write("%s=%s\n"%(keys,configFile.get("middleware_props",keys)))
```

I have been dwelling on this for 10 hours, any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I want to mention that strings are read fine,integers are not.

EDIT 2:

```
String sp = "/local/r/properties/middleware.properties";
        Properties p = new Properties();

            p.load(new FileInputStream(sp));
            this.serverhost = p.getProperty("Serverhost");
            this.serverport = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("Serverport").trim());
            this.buffersize = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("Clientmessagesize").trim());
```

This is how I load my property file.

EDIT: When I locally made the properties file myself it works,but gives an error here too when I use the python generated file.
It looks a bit like this :

```
serverport =5555
serverhost =dryad04.ethz.ch
clientmessagesize =200
```

I guess thats where the problem lies,the generation of properties file by my python code.

ERRORS :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.client.ClientInstance.<init>(ClientInstance.java:26)
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.tests.ClientThreadInstance.run(ClientThreadInstance.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.tests.ClientThreadInstance.run(ClientThreadInstance.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.client.ClientInstance.<init>(ClientInstance.java:26)
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.tests.ClientThreadInstance.run(ClientThreadInstance.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.client.ClientInstance.<init>(ClientInstance.java:26)
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.tests.ClientThreadInstance.run(ClientThreadInstance.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.client.ClientInstance.<init>(ClientInstance.java:26)
    at ch.ethz.rama.asl.tests.ClientThreadInstance.run(ClientThreadInstance.java:58)
```

Where line 26 of clientinstance is :

```
this.buffersize = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("Clientmessagesize"));
```

and line 58 of other class is :

```
client = new ClientInstance(client_id);
```

So the property file is the problem,somehow I mess up the generation of the property file.

Comment: debug it, check if the p is not null, and then check if p.getPropery("db_port") is not null, the code will throw NPE if p.getProperty("db_port") is null

Comment: How did you load the properties? Did you chmod the properties file after your python script created it so that your java program can read it properly?

Comment: @BOND I did not chmod it, why should I have to do that and how?

Comment: @sleiman Jneidi this is only a problem for numeric values, strings are fine.

Comment: @LoveMeow because you need to make sure the java program has the proper permission to access the properties file. Just use linux command: chmod 755 filename.properties.   755 is a usual file access pattern used in production system.

Comment: @BOND Rubbish. Listen to what you're being told. If permissions were the problem, he wouldn't have got this far, and he wouldn't know that non-numeric properties worked.

Comment: yes,and thats what I have posted

Comment: thats the property file that I generate and place on the server.

Comment: @EJP When I mentioned the OP needs to check permission, there isn't an update on that non-numeric thing yet. My last comment is only to answer why we need to check permission. "The program works fine locally, but on the server it throws NullPointException" - leads to my question on the permission. So you should read the comments more carefully.

Comment: Try using p.get("property") instead of p.getProperty("property") and see if that makes a difference...

Comment: No difference! I am really confused as to why its giving so much problem with numbers! Strings are fine.

Comment: @BOND Permission problems do not cause `NullPointerExceptions.`

Comment: @EJP permission doesn't cause NullPointerExceptions directly, that's why I asked how the properties are loaded

Comment: @LoveMeow Once again you have misled us. The exception you have now posted is not a `NullPointerException` at all. It is a `NumberFormatException.`

Comment: Im sorry I made a mistake. I have been staring at it for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the property you're looking for isn't in the file at all, so `Properties.getProperty()` returns null, so `String.trim()` gets an NPE.

Have a look at the stack trace: which should have been included in your question. And check your property names.

**EDIT** Now that you have finally disclosed that the actual problem is a `NumberFormatException`, this can only mean that the property value isn't numeric.

But I've had enough.

Comment: I think its because of the space after the word? I will post the error file soon.

Comment: @LoveMeow What space? after what word? You should also have posted the property file itself in your question.

Comment: I have posted the property file .

Comment: @LoveMeow I agree: get rid of the space. Note that what you posted in your original question is simply not true. You don't have `db_port=34` at all.

Comment: That was an example I posted, I have 2-3 property files with the same problem.

Comment: Rubbish. It was an example of one that works, not of one that doesn't work. It wa irrelevant and misleading.

Comment: It is an example of one that doesnt work. It still doesnt. This is the one generated by my python script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the python script posted above took the variable from the configuration file and made them all small case, as you can see above the name `'Servername'` became `servername`, breaking my head with this code led me to not see the obvious,now I don't know why the script I wrote did that, but I am not a python expert, I just made all my variable small case now!!

Thank you to all who tried to help.